# MacBook Pro Early 2015 barely charging

Tags: battery, charging

I got a second-hand MBP about a week ago and today I noticed that when I ran the battery to around 50% it wouldn't charge back. I installed coconutBattery and it shows the charging rate fluctuating at 0-10W.

[image: coconutBattery screenshot]

How do I make my MBP charge properly? Could this be due to faulty charger? I already tried a SMC reset.

Comment: Please tell us what size computer you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear this up, this was a 13'' MBP.

I've tested with other chargers and other people's MacBooks and found out my charger was faulty. Got a new one and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

That charge rate does seem low, but I am no expert.  Do you have the original charger?  Also, which machine do you have?

There are different chargers for the 13 and 15 inch models.  The 15 inch models are 85 Watt chargers and the 13 inch models are 60 watts.

As for the chargers going bad, yep they die all the time.  Usually the cable frays, but the components in the charger also die from time to time.